# Laravel - Columns updates after logout

Tags: laravel-4

I've created a login and logout.
But When I want to logout, he updates my Created_at, updated_at and remember_token colum's

Logout:

```
public function logout() {
    Auth::logout(); // logout user
    return Redirect::to('login'); //redirect back to login
}
```

How can i fix that he not update my created_at colum?

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want to update `created_at`? Your code shouldn't be updating that column.

Comment: No, when i logout he update the created_at colum, but that may not update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `Auth::logout();` does refresh all that data.

Otherwise you can try to add this code in your class:

```
public static $timestamps = false;
```